# How can I drop privileges in Perl?

Tags: linux, perl, security, privileges

I created a server program that will be started as root. After it is started I want to drop privileges to another user. How can I do this securely?

Comment: Not so good with linux, but maybe spawn a new process running as 'nobody'?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [Privileges::Drop](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Privileges-Drop).

Answer (score 5):

You don't really need a module, although the one linked by Benji York looks pretty nice.

It's a simple matter of setting the UID via `$<` and `$>`.  See [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$%3C) for further information on these.  You can also set the GID this way using `$(` and `$)`; note that you need to set `$) = "$target_gid $target_gid"` if you want to drop supplemental groups. Don't forget to test for success afterwards.

Comment: good point.  I imagined he'd just use the drop priv module, and there's really no reason not to, or I'd have provided an example.  It would look much like the source for the module though.